# Windows Server 2008 R2 - backup error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I have a serious problem, I need to recover a file from the backup, which is done automatically, but yesterday ended with an error

[image]

Is there any way that I can recover the file from  D drive?

Comment: what happens when you try?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what it says under the Errors tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Shadow Copies enabled on D:\ drive then you may be able to recover the file from there.

To access shadow copies, right click the disk in "Computer" select properties, then Previous versions.

Also, looking at the screen shot above, the D:\ backup seems to have completed, so although the backup set did'nt finish, is it possible that the backup of the D:\ does exist. If so it should be accessible.

Comment: Shadow Copies disabled probably.

I see that in this way [screen](http://i.imgur.com/UO7vI.jpg) and [second screen](http://i.imgur.com/PIJSx.jpg)

Comment: Yeah looks like they are.. My other point still stands, if that backup set failed, but the backup of D:\ was successful then if you go to the location where you backup, you might actually find the backup of D:\ from that failed set.
If this is a filesever, it might be worth switching on shadow copies, if the server has high disk IO, (database etc) then be carefull about reducing IO throughput.

Comment: My folder where the backup does contain such information current [sceen](http://i.imgur.com/Ys9lw.jpg). Backup doing since 2011 and until 15 august perform well. A 16 already shows me an error. Only now I noticed it because it works from there a long time and the previous IT does not took care of it. I do not really understand what's going on with Reducing IO throughput and what to do about it

Comment: does the file you are looking to restore exist in the folder you have a screenshot of?
if so then you should be o.k to copy the file out of there and to the location you need to restore it. Make sure you rename the file you are replacing first, so that you can roll back if needed.

My comment about reducing disk IO  is in relation to shadow copies, if a disk that you are running shadow copies on is used for high IO operations, then enabling shadow copies could reduce performance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy

Comment: This folder contains the VHD files, so I do not know what they are hidden inside and they have the tens of GB. Apparently my backup does not copy of the mirror only collect everything in one VHD file.

Comment: O.k so it sounds like you are backing up virtual machines?
if so you could use a tool like .NET DiscUtils, WinImage and R1soft Hyper-V VHD Explorer
They may let you get at the file you are trying to get to, but i cant promise anything, and i have never used any of those tools...
source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_%28file_format%29

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use these programs and let you know if it works